# Narrow to a sparse tree?

Tags: org-mode

There are times I prefer to work in a sparse tree instead of an agenda, namely ease of quick edits.

However the sparse tree, even with all folds level set to on (e.g. `org-show-siblings` and others), still the tree still shows tasks/headlines in a folded state.  I would prefer them to be entirely hidden, just like `org-narrow-to-subtree` (C-x n s).

This only works with a single subtree.  Is there a way to extend the narrowing to all of the sparse tree, and completely hide the non-sparce tasks/headlines?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem.  I just ran `org-sparse-tree` and only the matching headings and entries were shown.  Have you checked the `org-show-context-detail` option?  Also, have you tried `org-occur`?

Comment: This is a common use-case for me as well. I have found alphapapa's [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql/blob/master/README.org#org-ql-sparse-tree) doing what I needed. Please, give it a try and let me know if that helps.